# How to compare rows with out returning it in a query

Tags: sql-server-2005

I am trying to count the no of buses based on no of conditions. Problem is in a subquery it is returning 2 rows. I am expecting the count to be = 1 if all conditions are true. but it is giving it according to returned rows. Can u plz help how can i just compare rows instead of returning rows.

Comment: Please clarify your question. Your subquery is returning 2 rows? You don't like that? Can you post your SQL?

Comment: Following is the subquery that is returning 2 rows based on the following condition...I want just comparision not results. Any way of doing this
       SELECT 
   'x'
  FROM  
   DP 
  WHERE 
   dp_id = DPT.dp_id 
   having DPT.p_datetime = min(p_datetime) or DPT.a_datetime = max(a_datetime)

Comment: in this I am getting 2 rows with min and max times. All I want is just comparison not the rows.

Answer (score 0):

In your comment you state that this is the subquery that returns two rows.

```
SELECT 'x' FROM DP WHERE dp_id = DPT.dp_id having DPT.p_datetime = min(p_datetime) or DPT.a_datetime = max(a_datetime)
```

What would you like to compare? If you want rows in your outer query where the subquery returns anything you can use the EXISTS keyword:

```
SELECT * FROM DTP WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 'x' FROM DP WHERE dp_id = DPT.dp_id having DPT.p_datetime = min(p_datetime) or DPT.a_datetime = max(a_datetime));
```

Is that what you mean? If not, please clarify what you mean by "compare rows" as it is rather ambiguous.